Jetpack Composable/Kotlin: How to sort a collection produced by a DataSource based on the resource
I'm working on an app with Jetpack Composable and Kotlin.
I have a model class that contains a string resourceId, and a datasource that produces a collection of model objects. I would like that collection to be sorted based on the string resource referenced by the resourceId.
But apparently stringResource() is considered composable(why??), so I can't call it within a List.sortedBy() lambda either within my datasource or my UI.
What's a good practice to get around this so I can sort my collection alphabetically?
My Model:
data class Topic(
    @StringRes val stringResourceId: Int,
    val attendees: Int = 0,
    @DrawableRes val imageResourceId: Int
)

A Datasource:
class Datasource() {
    fun loadTopics(): List<Topic> {
        return listOf<Topic>(
            Topic(R.string.automotive, 0, R.drawable.automotive),
            Topic(R.string.biology, 0, R.drawable.biology),
        )
        // can't add .sortedBy({ stringResource(it.stringResourceId) })
        // because stringResource is composable (!?!) but lambdas are not
    }
}


Are you using any dependency injection framework?

No. I'm still learning and am not there yet. I expect to look into Dagger before long.

To access string resources in your Datasource class, you can inject the Context into the constructor. This allows you to retrieve the actual string values using context.getString().
Your modify code:
class Datasource(private val context: Context) {
    fun loadTopics(): List<Topic> {
        return listOf(
            Topic(R.string.automotive, 0, R.drawable.automotive),
            Topic(R.string.biology, 0, R.drawable.biology)
        ).sortedBy { context.getString(it.stringResourceId) }
    }
}

